# Search for Dataset in Azure Data Catalog using Column Tags

Tags: azure, azure-data-catalog

we are evaluating if Azure Data Catalog will meet our needs and one of our questions is if we can search for Datasets based on column tags. For example, if some of my datasets have the column tag "xyz" for one of their columns, can I search for all datasets with a column tag "xyz" and get all the datasets that have a column (any column) with the tag "xyz"?

Also, can this be done programmatically through the REST APIs? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last I checked you can tag individual columns and you can search on those tags. And REST based search API supports an explicit tag search syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The search at AzureDataCatalog.com will include column tags, column names, and object tags etc. If you implement the high tier options, you can roll up tags into business glosseries. For example the business might use "external supplier" but common alternative's used around the business might be 'panel vender' or 'agency' but really they all mean the same thing.

The full search syntax reference can be found here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datacatalog/data-catalog-search-syntax-reference